# How to use pouchdb-authentication on node?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, pouchdb

I am trying to use pouchdb-authentication on node with no lock. In the browser, it works fine but when I use it in node I get some errors about PouchDB having no method login. Here is some code.[image]

Anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pouchdb-authentication isn't designed to to work in Node. I'd recommend Nano as an alternative. There's some discussion in [this Github issue](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication/issues/18).